# What is wrong with this exercise in do Carmo's Differential Geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry

This is an exercise in do Carmo's Differential Geometry:

> Let $\alpha : I \longrightarrow S$ be a curve parametrized by arc length $s$, with nonzero curvature. Consider the parametrized surface \begin{align}\textbf{x}(s,v)=\alpha(s)+vb(s), & s \in I, -\epsilon < v < \epsilon, \epsilon > 0\end{align}
>   where $b$ is the binormal vector of $\alpha$. Prove that if $\epsilon$ is small, $\textbf{x}(I \times (-\epsilon, \epsilon)) = S$ is a regular surface over which $\alpha(I)$ is a geodesic (*thus, every curve is a geodesic on the surface generated by its binormals*).

An [errata online](https://webspace.yale.edu/math435_s07/files/errata.pdf) says that the first conclusion of this exercise is wrong:

> p. 262. Exercise 17: The first conclusion is false: It can happen that for all $\epsilon > 0$, the set $\textbf{x}(I \times (-\epsilon,\epsilon))$ fails to be a regular surface. (Consider a curve $\alpha : (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\alpha(s)$ approaches $(0,0,0)$ from the same direction as $s \rightarrow 0^+$ or $s \rightarrow 1^-$, and such that the part of $\alpha$ near $s=0$ is contained in a plane, and the part of $\alpha$ near $s=1$ is contained in a different plane.)

I don't quite understand the counterexample in the errata. Can somebody help to explicitly construct the curve $\alpha$?

Comment: Maybe something like this: the two parabolas parameterized as $(t,t^2,0)$ and $(t,0,t^2)$ are both tangent to the $x$-axis at the origin, but they approach the origin in different planes. Not that this is an example of the curve he mentions, but this is how it could happen.

Answer (score 2):

In the original exercise it is assumed that the curve $\alpha$ is a Frenet curve, that is, its second derivative by the arc length does never vanish. Otherwise the binormal vector is not defined. If there is a jump in the binormal vector then
there will be a bend in the surface. So it is not really a differentiable surface.